# Are helicopter searchlights fixed or movable?

Tags: helicopter, search-and-rescue, aircraft-external-lights

Can the helicopter crew move the helicopter searchlights or are they always fixed at a specific location on the helicopter?

They are used by rescue helicopters mostly but I am not sure if crew can move them to look at specific area by some method or they are always fixed.

Comment: All light fixtures on a helicopter are fixed. Some, like search lights, can be pointed.

Comment: To make your question clearer, you might like to add a picture of a helicopter that shows the lights you're asking about.

Comment: For future reference: strobe lights are the 'flashing' lights that flash white every second or so.

Answer (score 2):

The question is some what unclear, but helicopters usually have some combination of 3 types of lights.

Landing light(s); fixed, sometimes pulsing, used for illuminating the area directly in front of and below the helicopter for landing.

Anti-collision light; fixed red and green and a strobe on the tail and sometimes the belly.

Search lights; directable, usually only used on military or para-public helicopters that fly at night. [SAR, Police, etc...]

Answer (score 1):

By "searchlight" I assume you mean the high intensity units used to identify ground objects at night (example: the "NightSun" series). Those are usually fully steerable with their motion often slaved to a steerable video camera. Control is done by someone other than the pilot who is sufficiently busy flying the aircraft.